# How do you properly import MapSource in Kivy?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, kivy

I'm cloning a repository that uses Kivy rapid prototyping as its interface. It was last updated a year ago and the original developer is not responding to issues - I thought I would ask here.

The program makes use of the `MapSource` Library and it imports it like this:

`#:import MapSource mapview.MapSource`

I get the error:

`Unable to import package 'mapview.MapSource'`

This is the first time I'm working with Kivy. What is the syntax to import `MapSource`?

Here is the full output of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 464, 
in execute_directives
mod = import('.'.join(package.split('.')[:-1]))
File "/home/pi/CoPilot/mapview/init.py", line 30, in 
from mapview.source import MapSource
File "/home/pi/CoPilot/mapview/source.py", line 8, in 
from mapview.downloader import Downloader
File "/home/pi/CoPilot/mapview/downloader.py", line 8, in 
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError, as_completed
ImportError: No module named concurrent.futures
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 2077, in 
MainApp().run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 799, in run
self.load_kv(filename=self.kv_file)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 596, in load_kv
root = Builder.load_file(rfilename)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 301, in load_file
return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 350, in load_string
parser = Parser(content=string, filename=fn)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 392, in init
self.parse(content)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 498, in parse
self.execute_directives()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang/parser.py", line 475, in execute_directives
package)
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "/home/pi/CoPilot/main.kv", line 31:
...
29:#:import MDThemePicker kivymd.theme_picker.MDThemePicker
30:#:import math math

31:#:import MapSource mapview.MapSource
32:
33:#on_press: Animation(x=newposition or y=newposition).start(id) #to animate things
...
Unable to import package 'mapview.MapSource'
```

this is a link to the repository:

[Repository for CoPilot](https://github.com/Joelzeller/CoPilot)

Thank you all for your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly want [garden.mapview](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.mapview)

to install it, you can use `garden` the kivy tool to install kivy modules, if garden is already installed (should be the case when you install kivy), it should be as simple as.

`garden install --app mapview`

(`--app` is not mandatory, it just puts the flower in the app dir instead of in ~/.kivy/garden)

if not, you could either `pip install kivy-garden` or you could create a `lib` directory in your app and `git clone git@github.com:kivy-garden/garden.mapview.git` into it, because it's what the tool does.

Comment: Thank you. I believe i installed that - will redo and report back. Thanks again

Comment: Which way did you try? with garden install? or git clone?

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update: you can just install it with pip:

```
python -m pip install mapview
```

the current import is

```
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapSource
```

Further information:
https://mapview.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/